# Configure Oracle database (first time user)

Tags: oracle, windows, installation, oracle-12c

I am trying to learn how to use Oracle Database. I downloaded the Standard Edition version 12c from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html.

I successfully installed it (I think). I don't know how to proceed now. I was researching online and found the the file `tnsnames.ora` in `D:\Programs\Oracle\app\Admin\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN`. I found out something is using port 1521. So I went to `localhost:1521` in my browser, but nothing comes up.

Is there a web interface? Can I install one?

I also opened up `SQLDeveloper` and made a local connection. When I try to open up `/ as sysdba`, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.xml.NavigatorHook.getConnectionType(NavigatorHook.java:81)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.ObjectFactoryRegistry.createFactory(ObjectFactoryRegistry.java:157)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.ObjectFactoryRegistry.getFactory(ObjectFactoryRegistry.java:146)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.ConnectionFilter.getFactory(ConnectionFilter.java:95)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.ConnectionFilter$1.doWork(ConnectionFilter.java:119)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.ConnectionFilter$1.doWork(ConnectionFilter.java:104)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:515)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:682)
```

If someone can help me understand how to get everything set up (with a web interface), I would greatly appreciate it. I have watched videos and read articles but I am just not getting it.

I just want to be able to make Java programs that can communicate with the database using JDBC. I need to learn for my new job. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36596/discussion-between-cee-c-and-jsapkota).